# How to use Reactjs JSX based HTML in apex charts (bar) x axis label instead of simple string

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, richtext

I am using a bar chart from apexcharts in a reactjs application. I have rich text and I want to show it as the x-axis label of that chart instead of a regular string.
Is there a way to do this? I want to keep the text formatting and styles.[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is style option for xaxis in ApexChart. You can find more in the [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/#style).

Example:

```js
const option = {
    xaxis: {
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                fontWeight: 400,
                cssClass: 'some_labels',
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the question was to use Rich Text which means that there will be html elements with different stylings for each...

Comment: @MuhammadZainEjaz can you elaborate? you want to style the text, right? or you want to display a "buildt component" into the chart?